# uninitialized constant Sprockets::SassCacheStore Error on Windows (Learn ruby on rails book)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I'm new to web development and I have been following the Learn ruby on rails tutorial by David Kehoe on a Windows machine. For the past couple of days I have been stuck on the same error and I have tried almost all possible solutions I can find on the internet.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Learn Rails" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Learn Rails" %>">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%# Modernizr is required for Zurb Foundation %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/modernizr' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
```

The problem is with the line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

I already have NodeJs installed and I dont think the problem is with any of the javascript files because it works without the css if I take out that line. I have also tried removing require tree which didn't help.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'


gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# learn-rails
gem 'activerecord-tableless' 
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0' 
gem 'figaro' 
gem 'gibbon' 
gem 'google_drive' 
gem 'high_voltage' 
gem 'simple_form' 
gem 'zurb-foundation' 
group :development do 
    gem 'better_errors' 
    gem 'quiet_assets' 
    gem 'rails_layout' 
end
```

And application.css.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Is there anyone else who has had this problem and found a solution?

This is the stack trace for the current error. For some reason it changed from wrong number of arguements (1 for 2) to (3 for 2):

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (3 for 2):
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/sass_cache_store.rb:14:in `_store'
  sass (3.4.15) lib/sass/cache_stores/base.rb:51:in `store'
  sass (3.4.15) lib/sass/engine.rb:414:in `_to_tree'
  sass (3.4.15) lib/sass/engine.rb:309:in `to_tree'
  sass (3.4.15) lib/sass/engine.rb:343:in `_dependencies'
  sass (3.4.15) lib/sass/engine.rb:331:in `dependencies'
  compass-rails (2.0.4) lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:36:in `evalua
te'
  tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_proces
sors'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_
cache'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initiali
ze'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_proces
sors'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_
cache'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initiali
ze'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:30:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:89:in `[]'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:230:in `lookup_asset_for
_path'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:190:in `check_errors_for
'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:159:in `block in stylesh
eet_link_tag'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:158:in `stylesheet_link_
tag'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_ht
ml_erb___453486602_48019296'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render
_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render
_template'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render
'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template
'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_te
mplate'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_b
ody'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_b
ody'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block
 (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in
 ms'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block
 in render'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `clean
up_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `c
leanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `rende
r'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `defau
lt_render'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_a
ction'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_act
ion'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in proces
s_action'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels)
 in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_act
ion_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'

  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action
'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block
 in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in ins
trument'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `
instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `proce
ss_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `proce
ss_action'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `p
rocess_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispa
tch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve
'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call
'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in
 call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callba
cks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_cal
l'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_cal
l'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `c
all'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
start_thread'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using an old alpha release of compass, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/195).

After reading this Github [Issue](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/155) It sounds like the working combo of gems is:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.4'
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok I changed compass-rails to 2.0.4 in my Gemfile and I also had to change Sass-rails to 5.0.1 but now I'm getting this error in the command line: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/r
ails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (N
ameError)  and a lot more lines after that. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are not. check out this issue https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/315

Try specifically declaring gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'`

Comment: Yh I changed it but now I am getting the error: ArgumentError at /
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) when I am on local host.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: I have added the trace to the question.

Comment: Ahh, found a GH issue for this https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/155

Try 5.0 and 2.0.4

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked when I added gem "compass-rails", github: "Compass/compass-rails", branch: "master" and gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0' then running bundle update. You have been such a great help.

Comment: Awesome! I'm sorry it took so long, sprockets can be a pain at first. And Sass-rails really need to sort this issue out, it keeps happening.  And no worries, its part of the Ruby and Rails culture. Pass it on when you can. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this, and the following worked for me (as Zuru mentioned in a sub-comment - posting for easier readability).

```
gem "compass-rails", github: "Compass/compass-rails", branch: "master"
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0
```

Comment: you're missing a quotation after the sprockets version number, I wanted to add it but since it's too short for a modification stack overflow is rejecting my edit